# discord.js 12.5.3 can't send message, but status online

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Index.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ disableMentions: 'everyone' });
require('dotenv').config();
const Eco = require("quick.eco");
client.eco = new Eco.Manager();
client.db = Eco.db; 
client.config = require("./config");
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();
const fs = require("fs");

fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(f => {
        if (!f.endsWith(".js")) return;
        const event = require(`./events/${f}`);
        let eventName = f.split(".")[0];
        client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
    });
});

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(f => {
        if (!f.endsWith(".js")) return;
        let command = require(`./commands/${f}`);
        client.commands.set(command.help.name, command);
        command.help.aliases.forEach(alias => {
            client.aliases.set(alias, command.help.name);
        });
    });
});


client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Message.js

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
let visitor = require('../database/visitor.json');
let level = require('../database/level.json');
let place = require('../database/place.json');
let money = require('../database/money.json');

module.exports = async (client, message) => {
  if (message.content === "market") {
    message.reply(`yup, what?`);
  }
  if(!visitor[message.author.id]){
    visitor[message.author.id] = {
      totalvis: 0,
      totalbuyer: 0
    };
  }
  if(!level[message.author.id]){
    level[message.author.id] = {
      level: 1,
      exp: 0
    };
  }
  if(!place[message.author.id]){
    place[message.author.id] = {
      pla: "Hongria"
    };
  }
  if(!money[message.author.id]){
    money[message.author.id] = {
      balance: 20
    };
  }
  if(level[message.author.id].exp > 300) {
    let amount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 60) + 20;
    money[message.author.id].balance = money[message.author.id].balance + amount;
    level[message.author.id].level++;
    level[message.author.id].exp = 0;
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`${message.author.username} Level Up`)
      .addField(`Rewards`, `+ ${amount} Money`)
      .setColor("#E5E5E5")
      .setTimestamp()
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
  fs.writeFile('./database/visitor.json', JSON.stringify(visitor, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  fs.writeFile('./database/level.json', JSON.stringify(level, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  fs.writeFile('./database/place.json', JSON.stringify(place, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
  });
  fs.writeFile('./database/money.json', JSON.stringify(money, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
  });
    if (!message.guild || message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.id === client.config.countChannel) require("../counter")(message, client);
    client.prefix = client.db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`) ? client.db.fetch(`prefix_${message.guild.id}`) : client.config.prefix;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(client.prefix)) return;
    let args = message.content.slice(client.prefix.length).trim().split(" ");
    let commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    let command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(commandName));
    if (!command) return;
    client.ecoAddUser = message.author.id;
    command.execute(client, message, args);
};
```

Command.js

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const fs = require('fs');

exports.execute = async (client, message, args) => {
  if (!client.config.admins.includes(message.author.id)) return;
  message.channel.send("**Rebooting system..**").then(m => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            m.edit("**Wait a sec...**").then(ms => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    ms.edit("**Done.**")
                }, 3000)
            })
        }, 3000);

    })
    
    .then(message => process.exit())
    .then(() => client.login(process.env.TOKEN))
}

exports.help = {
    name: "reboot",
    aliases: ["rb"],
    usage: `reboot`
}
```

I use Discord.js version 12.5.3, my discord bot status is online, but if I try some command, my bot not send any message but in console, no errors. I used to be able to use this method, but now I want to try to make a discord bot again, and I use the same code without changing anything, but now my bot can't send any messages

Comment: That's because you don't have [intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents) enabled. You need to enable `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent   to send messages.

Answer (score 0):

I turn Privileged Gateway Intents in Discord Developer Portal, and it work!